# Is there a way to fix bad block without unmounting?

Tags: filesystem, umount, badblocks

I was thinking about running a bad sector check up on my system. Is it possible to do that without unmounting the primary filesystem? I want to check it on the system that is currently running.

Comment: Bad blocks aren't fixable. They can be "set aside". marked as not usable in a format process. And no, whatever attempt at that MUST be done unmounted.

Comment: This is what LiveUSB "Try Ubuntu" environments are for.

Comment: Thanks everyone.